# Why does curbstomping work?

Tags: self-defense, self-training

Why is curbstomping dangerous?

Comment: Hi John! For future reference, being a bit more specific makes for better questions. For example, you could ask about specific aspects of the question. Some examples: Why is it dangerous to execute? Why is it dangerous to be on the receiving end? (... which should be pretty obvious given some cursory research.) Why is it more dangerous from a legal perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the traditional [curb stomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curb_stomp) attack of setting a person's jaw along the curb, and then applying a heavy stomping blow to the back of the head, it basically applies the force along a fairly weak joint (the jaw), generally involves cranial trauma between possible skull damage and the brain getting bounced around, and creates some severe dental trauma. If the stomp is not directly to the back of the head, there's a decent chance of neck and spinal injuries as well, as the body is forced below the level of the curb while the head is kept in place.

Lastly, even if the initial attack doesn't cause death due to cranial trauma, the combination of likely unconsciousness or paralysis with mouth trauma can lead to the victim choking to death on their own blood.

It's also dangerous to the person performing it because it is a very deliberate move with known deadly consequences, so the odds are good that you will be charged with premeditated murder.

Comment: The broader principle, which is found in many martial arts, is applying force in a way that a joint is weak in.

Comment: @Macaco Branco So you are saying that there are multiple modes of injury?

Comment: @JohnKaine: You can see some discussion of the various injuries (and the myth that it's likely to kill via teeth driven into the sinus cavity) [here](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=405248).